# Funtion close_window() { if

Tags: jquery, html, function, if-statement

I've download a Scrip On page Extension, and I need a tab close everytime duration-holder audio is higher than 01:00

There's the code original code from the page

```
<div class="duration-holder">04:02</div>
```

In this case is higher than 1:00 i need this to close

There's the code that I try.. but it didn't work. Please help...

```
 function close_window() {
    if ($('div.duration-holder 00:00').length > 01:00) {
    close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You want `if (parseInt($('div.duration-holder').text()) > 1)`. Though that works in minute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

You should use `$('div.duration-holder').text()` to get the value of the `div`.

That gives a `string`, now you should convert that `string` to `number`

So you should use,**`parseInt($('div.duration-holder').text())`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function close() {
                alert('> 1')
            }
            function close_window() {
                console.log(parseInt($('div.duration-holder').text()));
                if (parseInt($('div.duration-holder').text()) > 1) {
                    close();
                }
            }
            close_window();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="duration-holder">02:02</div>


</body>

</html>
```

[**Here is the Working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/F9WOF6kwGnDl362iT8Am?p=preview)